# Where do I stand with btrfs?

Tags: filesystem, raid, btrfs

First off, I understand btrfs is experimental and I should still have valid backups of all my data etc etc. No problems.

I have setup a btrfs RAID5 array across 4x 3TB drives;

```
Overall:
    Device size:                  10.92TiB
    Device allocated:                0.00B
    Device unallocated:           10.92TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                            0.00B
    Free (estimated):                0.00B      (min: 8.00EiB)
    Data ratio:                       0.00
    Metadata ratio:                   0.00
    Global reserve:               16.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)
```

Good. It appears to be setup correctly.

I'm using Kerenl 4.4.0-22-generic on Ubuntu. As I understand it, this includes a version of btrfs that has RAID56 implemented?

My problem is, when I run `btrfs fi usage /storage` I get the following output

```
nick@vnas:/tmp$ sudo btrfs fi usage /storage
WARNING: RAID56 detected, not implemented
WARNING: RAID56 detected, not implemented
WARNING: RAID56 detected, not implemented
Overall:
    Device size:                  10.92TiB
    Device allocated:                0.00B
    Device unallocated:           10.92TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                            0.00B
    Free (estimated):                0.00B      (min: 8.00EiB)
    Data ratio:                       0.00
    Metadata ratio:                   0.00
    Global reserve:               16.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)

Data,RAID5: Size:3.00GiB, Used:1.75MiB
   /dev/sdb        1.00GiB
   /dev/sdc        1.00GiB
   /dev/sdd        1.00GiB
   /dev/sde        1.00GiB

Metadata,RAID5: Size:1.03GiB, Used:112.00KiB
   /dev/sdb      352.00MiB
   /dev/sdc      352.00MiB
   /dev/sdd      352.00MiB
   /dev/sde      352.00MiB

System,RAID5: Size:96.00MiB, Used:16.00KiB
   /dev/sdb       32.00MiB
   /dev/sdc       32.00MiB
   /dev/sdd       32.00MiB
   /dev/sde       32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdb        2.73TiB
   /dev/sdc        2.73TiB
   /dev/sdd        2.73TiB
   /dev/sde        2.73TiB
```

My problem is this `WARNING: RAID56 detected, not implemented`

Does this mean that RAID56 is not implimented properly and if I have a failure I won't be able to recover?

Thanks

Comment: Btrfs is considered stable and ready for production since a few years except for a shrinking list of features like RAID (especially levels 5 and 6). Even RAID0 and RAID1 are considered stable these days.

Answer (score 1):

I am in no way certain about this, but I suspect that it refers to the usage calculation and not the RAID implementation in itself. It's true that the RAID 5/6 implementation has known bugs and limitation, but it is none the less implemented.

If I'm mistaken I would gladly be corrected!

edit: Looks like I might be [right](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg41478.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#Features), "the RAID 5 and RAID 6 implementations are considered flawed"; also see the [status](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Status) page at kernel.org. It sounds like you are right, RAID56 is not yet implimented properly. If you want RAID 5 or 6 it is currently better to create a partition-level RAID device (using mdadm), and put the file system on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

The warning given is from the developer perspective. 
They do not consider RAID5/6 production ready.

Cite: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Status
You'll note that as of 12/2/16 the status shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Scrub + RAID56 | Unstable | will verify but not repair
---------------------------------------------------------------
RAID56         | Unstable | write hole still exists, parity not 
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Until that feature is considered production ready that warning will persist.

In respect to your question about recovery, you are correct in that it is unknown whether a recovery will be possible. There has been quite a bit of discovery shared within the btrfs mailing-list and currently users are recommended to move off of RAID5/6.